# Подменить Get метод в свойстве, или организовать событие для get

Tags: c#

Есть внешний класс со своим/и свойствами:

```
public class Extern 
{
  public string One {get; set;}
  ....
}
```

Каким образом, мне заменить у него get метод, допустим с помощью рефлексии, или как то среагировать, когда обращаются к свойству "One"?

Есть возможность поменять с помощью рефлексии значение этого свойства, может быть, как-то свой `{get; set;}` ему подсунуть?

Comment: Хм, а кто меняет свойства у него?

Comment: http://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception

Comment: Есть еще вариант, как если у свойства есть `DependencyProperty`, должно называться как пример, если свойство `One`, то обычно именуется как `OneProperty`, если такое есть, то просто вызываем метод `SetValue(OneProperty, "Тут значение");`

Comment: Если свойство виртуальное - можно реализовать декоратор

Answer (score 0):

К примеру есть класс:

```
public class Extern
{
    public string One { get; set; } 
}
```

Поменять значение через рефлексию:

```
var obj = new Extern();
Console.WriteLine(obj.One); // пустая строка
obj.GetType().GetProperty("One").SetValue(obj, "123");
Console.WriteLine(obj.One); // 123
```

Тип получаем через метод [`GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx). Поиск свойства выполняем через метод [`Type.GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx). Значение меняем через метод [`PropertyInfo.SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xb5dd1f1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
        private static string _one;
        public static string One
        {
            get
            {
                //Тут можно вставить событие
                return _one;
            }
            set
            {
                //Тут в принципе
                _one = value;
                //И здесь
            }
        }
```

Comment: Как? Класс не мой.

Comment: И вообще рефлексией если есть возможность лучше не пользоваться ибо накладные расходы возрастают во много много раз.

Comment: В таком случае вам копать в сторону DynamicProxy от Castle. Ну либо читать про динамическое редактирование IL, стандарными средствами в чужой огород не лязят